# How to format number using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

so I got this number format 00:30:00, I wanted to change that format into only this 30, is there any ways that I can use in JS ?

Comment: `'00:30:00'.split(':')[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = '00:30:00';
num = num.split(':')[1];
```

you can achieve by this.